# How to set repeating notification sound for certain time in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, timer, notifications

I want to create a custom notification using `NotificationComapat.Builder`. I want this notification having repeating sound (sound is from project's raw folder) and the duration should be 60 seconds.

I managed to get the sound but I don't know how to set it to repeat for that time duration. Please help!

P.S.: is there any way without timer task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by the following

```
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),          R.raw.tone);
    mp.start();
 mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()          {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

and your Thread Should stop the Media Player by

```
   mp.stop();
```

after the sleeping of 60000 milliseconds.
hope it helps.

Comment: thanks it is working; in addition, i used 'mp.release();' instead